# openstack mitaka glance command error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openstack

I am try to install the glance in Ubuntu 14.04 
openstack mitaka is what I am trying to configure
but at the glance I got an error

command 
su -s /bin/bash glance -c "glance-manage db_sync"

[file link](https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/u/0/?ui=2&ik=73281908c8&view=att&th=15dea7d60a05dc9e&attid=0.1&disp=safe&realattid=f_j6eujseq0&zw&saddbat=ANGjdJ-YpXVOcLbEQptdPnXhYJICQos_ZpyMlT8FveeXBvJ53pWJCCIH8Jmlaa6hFkfXgi3RompctHmLQHdv1o3wWyb682AAw_E1-2oKiUrAHvEcr2g4xrUVjsE9V6jfOkhjAklqkkAn3MwVgCc1z2G53KTvtcQSWV5OrJjOdVFxjKfmZjNTeMU5HqmyJb2C5IImhVPCzQ9beUUxTGiX7JwwYneZ6mIzs1rRDpXajxA18bkWPxzl1n60MCNf9ZlY5Q5KKT0GVR9vgEiA3iJDERygAA0mcBMtcZkEdW1dKntT8jI9T-9Ul0jBWXzGPLuK3iF-5f975lFzlA9QtF9EgRX291Jbr40Tox89uoU11OFc4G5Aad2uOjyA5rBgsj6lYA-39f5BTM-KcnadDFcA88IC_XAtHDReYuxdtaBEfjTBj6EMPcZvG8omankbEhzFF4pNbahuI7vlYdrFtyAqNU99HnrJaYa8MEqIfs9fHT7C0OIbxoUzriwZSXIcBnEv15IlujEphRmudNmFZitXC_V1Wxa81_cQGPFMN7_ZBLzD-C0954n1PFLAWblHWQUJaoUVGtPju3ZSdIDMA1UUfo6ZtmNV7nUR7ahAQEfLl-3g9qFCSXMG9sncge3Z69M)

any solution

thank you

Comment: You may want to host the logs on pastebin, or something that is more easily accessible. The error should help diagnose the issue. It could be related to MySQL not being up, or user/password information is incorrect, or the DB wasn't created.

Comment: which log files can you name some of it

Comment: Post the output from the command you are running, so we can see which error is being posted. You can look at /var/log/glance*.log files to see if there are any relevant errors as well. You can also see debug info (may want to remove passwords/other information) by using `glance --debug {other commands}`